# inverse function theorem for analytic functions whose derivative might vanish

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $x(t), y(t)$ are monotone increasing functions, and $f$ and $g$ are real-analytic functions that are not identically zero.

If $f(x(t)) = g(y(t))$ for all $t$, does it follow that $x$ is an analytic function of $y$?

If $f' \neq 0$ I could use the inverse function theorem to patch together an analtyic $x = f^{-1}(g(y))$; can anything go wrong if $f'$ vanishes at isolated points?

Comment: maybe I'm misreading something, but, take the bump function (smooth but, not analytic at zero) and add $t/2$. I think that makes an increasing function. Take $x(t)=y(t)$ the modified bump and let $f=g$ then certainly $f(x(t))=g(y(t))$ for all $t$ and it does not follow that $x$ or $y$ is analytic. Surely I misinterpret the spirit of the question.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I've clarified the question a bit... I'm asking if $x$ is an analytic function of $y$; in your example if I understand correctly $x(y) = y$ which is certainly analytic.

Comment: I see, and I'm tempted to follow your solution. Certainly we know that for such $t$ which give $f '(x(t))=0$ then $g'(y(t))=0$ as well (since $x'(t),y'(t)$ are nonzero and the chain rule tells us $f'(x(t))x'(t) = g'(y(t))y'(t)$). Perhaps that is useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, things can go wrong if $f'$ vanishes. For example: $x(t)=t$, $y(t)=t^3$, $f(x)=x^3$, $g(x)=x$. Then $f(x(t))=g(y(t))=t^3$, but $x$ cannot be written as a differentiable function of $y$.